# Rails Gecoder Nearby Logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

I am trying to return a default location using the Geocoder Gem if there is nothing nearby. However, my logic always returns the first location in DB, which is what I want but it should return a valid nearby request if conditions met. Here is my controller:

```
def nearby
    respond_to do |format|
      @locations = Location.nearby([nearby_location_params[:latitude], nearby_location_params[:longitude]], nearby_location_params[:distance])
    if @location == 1
      format.json { render json: @locations, status: :success }
    else
      @locations = Location.first
      format.json { render json: @locations }
    end
  end
end
```

Its my guess that: if @location == 1 is the culprit.

Here I am trying to say, if the conditions met in distance param, show that location. If not, show first in DB.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

you're not setting `@location`, but even if, you would not want to compare it to an integer, since its supposed to be a location object. i think tou want something like

```
if @locations.any?
```

also, i'd put the default location also in an array, so that the `@locations` is always the (sort of) same type: something iterable.

Comment: That worked but looking for suggestions for a better, more rails like approach. I could seed to the database with a default\first location but this doesn't seem like the best way to do this.

Comment: maybe i don't exactly understand what you mean, but since it always comes down to "if no locations found, use the default location", i don't know how you would be able to get rid of that if condition.

Comment: How would you better define the default location besides:

else
      @locations = Location.first

Comment: that really depends on your application, e.g.: it could be based on the logged in user or based on the visitor's ip. in any case, i would put the "calculation" of the default in a method.